# Android: How to ensure/test that ProGuard is enabled?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I am trying to enable `Proguard` on a very simple "hello world" application.

I have took the steps outlined below, however the code is the exact same as an application without proguard enable when I run it through `APKtool` and `JD-GUI` in order to reverse engineer it. I.e. my code is not obfuscated in any way.

I am aware I am very likely doing something wrong.

I have took the following steps:

```
To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Then ran my application, but not in de-bug mode.

I then saved the .apk and decompliled, but all code is visible in its original state, i.e. not obfuscated.

Is there a way to know that Proguard has definitely been implemented in the Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to know that Proguard has definitely been implemented
>   in the Application?

The easiest way that i can think of is turn off the proguard, and create an APK (the 1st APK).

After that, turn on the proguard, and create the 2nd APK.

See if theres any difference in those 2 APK. The 2nd APK (with proguard) should be smaller than the 1st one.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, however the two are exactly the same size. I assume this means that proguard was not enabled. This is strange as I thought the only step needed for integration was to uncomment the line in the project.properties file? Which I have done.

Comment: @user4125772 It means the proguard is not working. Please post your proguard code. And no, you need to specify the what the proguard will "compress" in your proguard-android.txt or proguard-project.txt (based on your code)

Comment: What do you mean by my proguard code? The only thing I have changed is the uncommenting of that line in project.properties. Surely this should still obfuscate the code? Thanks